# $ \displaystyle \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{2n-1}$ convergence with alternating series test,absolute convergence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

$ \displaystyle \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{2n-1}$

How can I show in this case, that $u_{n} \rightarrow 0$?

I assume, that the serie is convergent

What about the absolute convergence?

Comment: Leibniz's Test shows the series converges.  Comparison with the harmonic series shows that it does not absolutely converge.

Comment: What is $u_n$? $\phantom{}$

Comment: Also grouping the terms by two :  $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{2n-1}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{4n+1}-\frac{1}{4n-1} =\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{-1/2}{(4n-1)(4n+1)}$ which converges absolutely by comparison with $\frac{1}{32}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$

Comment: @user1952009, a minor quibble with your comment:  the original series starts with a *positive* term, $1/3$, so the sum (since the terms are strictly decreasing in absolute value) is positive, not negative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the alternating series test, you can easily show that $ \displaystyle \frac{1}{2n-1}$ converges to $0$  since the denominator gets really big when $n$ goes to $\infty$. Also the sequence is decreasing since $$\frac{1}{2n-1} \geq \frac{1}{2n}$$ since by taking the reciprocals $$ 2n - 1 \leq 2n $$ which holds for every $n$.

For absolute convergence, consider the series $ \displaystyle \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{2n-1}$. By comparison test to $ \displaystyle \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{2n}$ we have that: $$  \displaystyle \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{2n} \leq \displaystyle \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{2n-1}$$ We know that the the first one is the multiple of the divergent harmonic series.
Since the smaller series diverges, so does the bigger one.
Thus the original series is conditionally convergent.

Comment: If you use Leibniz Test at the start, then you **already assume** the series is convergent, which is what you want to prove....

Comment: The test does not require the series to converge? It helps to show that it converges and that is, if the sequence is decreasing and it converges to 0. If either of these does not hold then the series does not converge.

Comment: Just now I payed attention to the fact the OP wrote he assume the series converges...

Comment: Ok, I added the statement about absolute convergence.